# How to Hide View on click?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, view, actionscript, hide

I'm building my own "slide in" menu with SplitViewNavigator in Flash Builder with Flex and ActionScript 3.

I need help on how to show/hide the left view. I'm aware that I should use the visible=false/true but I don't know how to make the view disappear via the button click.

I have a button as you can see and It calls a function, but what should the function do?
Something with if visible = false/true?
The name of the left view that I want to hide is "Meny".

So basically I want to know how to hide the left view via a button click.

```
<s:SplitViewNavigator width="100%" height="100%">

        <s:ViewNavigator id="meny" width="70%" height="100%" firstView="views.Meny"/>
        <s:ViewNavigator title="Content" id="content" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.Content">
            <s:navigationContent>
                <s:Button label="Meny" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
            </s:navigationContent>
        </s:ViewNavigator>
    </s:SplitViewNavigator>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `<s:Button click="svn.getViewNavigatorAt(0).visible=false" label="Click"/>`. If your button is in the same view as the split navigator, you can simply say meny.visible-=false

Comment: You man, are my hero! I tried it a lot of times with menyVisible when it was just meny.visible. Haha thanks! However, can I now apply some kind of transition on this visible=true/false? I want it to look like it's sliding, if that's possible?